# Multiple instances of CKeditor with fMath is not working in a form

Tags: php

I have integrated fMath plugin in CKeditor. I have a form with multiple textareas. But in this form, fMath is working only in the first textarea. Kindly help me out by suggesting how I can configure CKeditor correctly with fMath.

TIA.